# SOAP Login error for some Acumatica instances

Tags: soap, acumatica

Hello I have a C# tool that imports data into one of our custom forms in Acumatica.  It logins into the URL and imports data in batches.  It works fine for the most part, but we've run into one client whose instance we can't access.  I can call up their asmx page in the browser and everything looks fine but we get a strange error when the program invokes Login

```
 Exception thrown: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException' in System.Web.Services.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException' occurred in System.Web.Services.dll
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The request element <Login xmlns='http://www.acumatica.com/typed/'> was not recognized.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

Has anyone seen this error before? Here is my code snippet, it errors on Login.

```
_itemsScreen = new VendorItem.Screen();
        _itemsScreen.Url = url + "/Soap/SW200014.asmx";
        _itemsScreen.EnableDecompression = true;
        _itemsScreen.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        _itemsScreen.Timeout = 3600000;
        _itemsScreen.Login(username, password);
```

Comment: Are you able to view the service and its wsdl using Tools -> Web Service for that instance?

Comment: I am, it appears to be fine.